# e.parameter undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

Q: why is e.parameter.wfId undefined (in the log) after running the script below (as a web-app)

I call script with this URL

https://script.google.com/a/macros/gappspro.com/exec?service=my-webapp-key
without a parameter  (&wfId=somecharacters)

```
function doGet(e) {

    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Workflow Builder');

    var mainGrid = app.createGrid(2,1).setId('FILE_doGet_mainGrid');

    app.add(mainGrid);

    var wfId = '1234567890'  // FILE.doGet.randomString();

    mainGrid.setWidget(1,0, app.createTextBox().setValue(wfId).setId('wfId').setName('wfId'));

    var handler = app.createServerHandler('func');
    handler.addCallbackElement(mainGrid);

    Logger.log(e.parameter.wfId);     

    return app;
  } 

function func(e) {
  return x;
 }
```

I am trying to implement the workflow script from chapter 8 of james ferreira’s book Enterprise Application Essentials and in the add Docs section i ran into the problem that e.parameter.wfId in line “var wfRowArray = FILE.ssOps.getWfRowFromSS(e.parameter.wfId), “ is undefined when running the script. (on page 134 in the book, not the PDF).
In the example above i brought the code back to the essence of what is causing the error,...for me.

Answer (score 0):

`e.parameter.wfId` is only available in your func(e) function, not in the doGet. the variable `e` represents the elements of the `callBackElement` catch by the handler function.

Comment: thanks!  As i mentioned, i am trying to implement the workflow script from chapter 8 of james ferreira’s book Enterprise Application Essentials and in the "add Docs" section i ran into the problem that e.parameter.wfId in the line “var wfRowArray = FILE.ssOps.getWfRowFromSS(e.parameter.wfId),“ is undefined when running the script. (on page 134 in the book, not the PDF).

I can't figure out what i am doing wrong. 

I follow the book exactly and e.parameter.wfId is called on in the doGet(e) function itself, before callbackelement is executed.

Comment: sorry, I didn't pay attention to the url in the first line of your post... it is indeed nor the same e ;-), this one is suppose to come from the url itself

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, this is behaving as expected. 
You say "h-ttps://script.google.com/a/macros/gappspro.com/exec?service=my-webapp-key without a parameter (&wfId=somecharacters)"

So, I believe you are not passing any URL parameters to the script URL and therefore you get them as undefined.

If you call your script with the URL parameters, say 
h-ttps://script.google.com/a/macros/gappspro.com/exec?service=my-webapp&wfId=somecharacters
then you can expect to see e.parameter.wfld